# Change Sphinx's template for table of contents

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, templates, python-sphinx, toctree

I am using Sphinx with my own template to get a documentation style like the twitter bootstrap documentation: http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/getting-started.html

There you can see the navigation on the left, which is static and stays at the same place as you scroll.

It is therefore nescessary to render the table of contents which I already achieved with this function:

```
{{ toctree(maxdepth=1, collapse=False, includehidden=true) }}
```

That outputs me the following:

```
<ul class="current">
    <li class="toctree-l1 current"><a class="current reference internal" href="">Introduction</a></li>
    <li class="toctree-l1"><a class="reference internal" href="#installation">Installation</a></li>
    <li class="toctree-l1"><a class="reference internal" href="#roadmap">Roadmap</a></li>
</ul>
```

But in order to let it work with bootstrap I need the following output:

```
<ul class="nav nav-list bs-docs-sidenav">
    <li><a href="#introduction"><i class="icon-chevron-right"></i> Introduction</a></li>
    <li><a href="#installation"><i class="icon-chevron-right"></i> Installation</a></li>
    <li><a href="#roadmap"><i class="icon-chevron-right"></i> Roadmap</a></li>
</ul>
```

So my question is: How can I achieve that? Is there a template file for the `toctree()` function I can adjust?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and i used a mixed of self defined roles and jQuery to adjust this issues based on my role placement. jQuery will change all the stuff y need.

Comment: What are self defined roles? After all, I am also using jQuery to manipulate the html. I think this is not perfect, maybe Sphinx can be better in this case, for better customization of the templates...

Comment: Self defined roles is something like `:myrole:` which you can use to extend the markup. I do not think that this helps here. As far as I can tell so far, one has to modify the builder. Once I managed to do this, I will write a full answer here.